# Accessing arrays/lists within parameters using Flask

Tags: python, mongodb, datatable, flask, datatables

I'm tinkering with Flask + Datatables + Mongo to create a test web app. I'm using Datatables' in server-side data mode, and the parameters it's sending in request data are as follows:

```
columns[0][data]
columns[1][name]
columns[1][orderable]
columns[3][data]
columns[2][orderable]
columns[3][searchable]
order[0][dir]
columns[1][search][regex]
columns[3][orderable]
columns[0][search][value]
columns[2][searchable]
columns[3][search][regex]
columns[0][search][regex]
start
columns[0][searchable]
draw
columns[2][search][value]
columns[2][search][regex]
columns[1][data]
order[0][column]
columns[1][searchable]
columns[0][name]
columns[2][data]
columns[0][orderable]
search[value]
columns[3][name]
_
search[regex]
columns[1][search][value]
columns[2][name]
length
columns[3][search][value]
```

So as an example, I'd like to be able to access the "order" list to do things like

```
len(order)
```

To see how many items are in the list, but I can't because Flask is seeing each parameter as a separate item instead of lists. Is there any way to safely fix this?

In the Datatables documentation (https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) it says: "In most modern server-side scripting environments this data will automatically be available to you as an array."

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

So, I was able to solve this by simply telling Datatables to convert the POST to JSON before sending it. Then I just parse the JSON with Python and I get the desired result.

The datatables initialization to send JSON looks like this:

```
ajax: {
  url: 'myUrl',
  data: function ( d ) {
    return { 'd': JSON.stringify( d ) };
  }
}
```

Code ripped from here: https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/issues/311

This is probably bad from a security perspective, but I'm just developing this app for my own local use, so I'm not too worried.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any actual code, it's hard to say for certain, but my belief is that somewhere you have code similar to

```
order = request.args.get('order')
len(order)
```

The key to knowing what's happening here is `request.args`. It is a [`MultiDict`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict), a data structure provided by [Werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/).

As the documentation states, `MultiDict` is designed to work with multiple values sharing the same key. So why didn't your code work?

`MultiDict.get` returns the first value matching the key. To get all of the values, you need to use the [`MultiDict.getlist`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.getlist) method.

```
order = request.args.getlist('order')
len(order)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I *think* I tried that and got an empty list. So I just changed my approach a bit. See below.